# What is a good site or book for understanding base/radix?

Tags: number-theory

I have a hard time, understanding what base is, how to convert from one to another, and why is the conversion so?

And I can't find a site or book that explains all these in detail.

Comment: [This](https://brilliant.org/wiki/number-base/) article might be a good place to start.